# MognoDB,PyMongo:Remove the entry in database using only key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have stored the data in mongodb database.My each entry looks like below:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5926858fd51b6b4a399a800a'), u'james,2017-05-01': [u'2017-05-01', u'Cell', u'1', u'UT', u'Repo', u'1', u'Add extra information']}
```

As you can see my key is combination of username and date,i.e.username,data.
And the value is the list.

I want to remove the entry in the database using  key in my case it is username,data.
I am new to MongoDB. Can someone help me?

Comment: You want [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). Specifically `remove({ 'james,2017-05-01' { '$exists': True } })`

Comment: So will it remove from key only?

Comment: *"remove the entry in the database using key" Is what your question says. Do does this match the document that has this key and then remove that document? Yes it does. try the query conditions with a `.find()` first to see what is selected. All stated in the documentation link given as well as the linked answers. Read them, in order to understand.

Comment: You can try `db.collection.remove({ username: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } });`

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax of remove() method is as follows −

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.remove(DELLETION_CRITTERIA)
```

Consider the *test* collection has the following data.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec5), "title":"First"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec6), "title":"Second"}
```

Following example will remove all the documents whose title is 'First'.

```
db.test.remove({'title':'First'})
```

To Check :

```
db.test.find()
```

Comment: So it is required key,value par.Can't we remove using the key only?

Comment: In your case you can use  `db.test.remove({'username':'YourUserName'})` : if exist

Comment: Hi i my case key is username,date and value is dept,release.So query looks like username,date:dept,date,value.So I want to remove entry using key that is in my case it is username,date